# ASPNET 5 Authentication Scheme Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the code for the class `IdentityCookieOptions` [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/IdentityCookieOptions.cs), I can see that two properties, `ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme` and `ApplicationCookieAuthenticationType`, are defined.  Further, I can see, by default, that the value of the `ApplicationCookieAuthenticationType` property is set to `typeof(IdentityCookieOptions).Namespace + ".Application"` and the value of the `ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme`, by default, is set to the value of the `ApplicationCookieAuthenticationType` property.

What is the purpose of these two properties?  I see that some methods ask for authentication scheme while some ask for authentication type.